# Rx and Tx creating a lot of noise when floating on ESP8266 and Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, i2c, noise

I have connected an Arduino Pro-Mini 3.3V 8MHz to an ESP8266 via I2C.

The Arduino is in charge of collecting data from a thermistor (analog temperature) (T2) and a SI7021 (digital temperature) (T1).

The ESP8266 is in charge of sending the data received from the Arduino to an endpoint.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/ClemRz/Solar-Water-Heater-Monitor. In the res folder you will find a picture of the circuit.

The issue I am having is that as long as I leave the FTDI RS232 programmer connected to either the Arduino or the ESP I'm having a smooth response from the thermistor but as soon as I disconnect it, the response get some noise.
What is happening?

Here is a graph where we can see 3 phases: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsnvY.png

1. Programmer disconnected: some noise can be seen
2. Programmer connected: smooth noiseless curve
3. Programmer disconnected again: noisy

If I remove Rx and Tx and I leave GND connected to the FTDI I also observe that the reading is smooth and noiseless.

---

**Solved: I switched the wall adapter to a better quality one and it fixed the noise issue.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is hardware related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the wall adapter with a better quality one and it will fix the noise issue.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your circuit in Fritzing, if you are using a NTC Thermistor, you need to connect on pin to 5V and the other pin to your Analogic Input with a pull-down resistor. Just like this image.

[image: NTC Thermistor to Arduino]

I hope this help you to read good analog signals of the thermistor

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I followed the documentation provided here which uses a pull-up resistor: https://learn.adafruit.com/thermistor/using-a-thermistor

If that would be an issue how do you explain that I get no noise when connecting FTDI's GND pin?

Comment: You can also use a capacitor connected to the Analog Input and ground. This helps a lot to reduce noise from the 5V rail. This because the 5V rail is sensitive to the noise that can  make other components like switches, relays and communication buses. a 0.1uF capacitor may work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the power supply from when you disconnect the FTDI interface?

I've experienced the same issue when I don't wire the grounds properly. Double check all your grounds are wired together (from your main circuit and from the FTDI/USB). Remember ground is a voltage reference that must remain consistent throughout your circuit.

Comment: Thanks. The power supply comes from a wall adapter that I regulate with a LM1117-3.3. All components share the same GND.